# Discord.Net Dependency Map missing

Tags: c#, discord.net

I wanted to make a bot using a GitHub repo, but when I imported it, it said that `Depenency Map` was not found. I'm 99% sure it is part of `Discord.Commands` and this is the first part of the bot:

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Discord;
using Discord.WebSocket;
using Discord.Commands;

namespace DiscordBot
{
    class Program
    {
        private CommandService commands;
        private DiscordSocketClient client;
        private DependencyMap map;

        public static void Main(string[] args) => new Program().MainAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();

        public async Task MainAsync()
        {
            client = new DiscordSocketClient();
            commands = new CommandService();
            map = new DependencyMap();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like the GitHub repo you mentioned is using an older version of Discord.Net.

There's a legacy file on Discord.Net that describes this - [legacy.md](https://github.com/discord-net/Discord.Net/blob/ff0fea98a65d907fbce07856f1a9ef4aebb9108b/docs/faq/misc/legacy.md).

> I came from an earlier version of Discord.Net 1.0, and DependencyMap doesn't seem to exist anymore in the later revision? What happened to it?
> The DependencyMap has been replaced with Microsoft's [DependencyInjection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection) Abstractions. An example usage can be seen [here](https://github.com/foxbot/DiscordBotBase/blob/csharp/src/DiscordBot/Program.cs#L36).

Example usage taken from [Program.cs](https://github.com/foxbot/DiscordBotBase/blob/csharp/src/DiscordBot/Program.cs#L36)

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Discord;
using Discord.Commands;
using Discord.WebSocket;
using DiscordBot.Services;

namespace DiscordBot
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
            => new Program().MainAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();

        private DiscordSocketClient _client;
        private IConfiguration _config;

        public async Task MainAsync()
        {
            _client = new DiscordSocketClient();
            _config = BuildConfig();

            var services = ConfigureServices();
            services.GetRequiredService<LogService>();
            await services.GetRequiredService<CommandHandlingService>().InitializeAsync(services);

            await _client.LoginAsync(TokenType.Bot, _config["token"]);
            await _client.StartAsync();

            await Task.Delay(-1);
        }

        private IServiceProvider ConfigureServices()
        {
            return new ServiceCollection()
                // Base
                .AddSingleton(_client)
                .AddSingleton<CommandService>()
                .AddSingleton<CommandHandlingService>()
                // Logging
                .AddLogging()
                .AddSingleton<LogService>()
                // Extra
                .AddSingleton(_config)
                // Add additional services here...
                .BuildServiceProvider();
        }

        private IConfiguration BuildConfig()
        {
            return new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .AddJsonFile("config.json")
                .Build();
        }
    }
}
```